# Cypress: Check if Select Option Exists

Tags: javascript, select, cypress

I'm trying to check if there is an option in my select using the code below, but it keeps failing, can somenone give some help?

My Select have about 70 names and I'm trying to loop all them looking for the specific name.

```
        cy.get('[id="names"] option').each(($ele) => {
            expect($ele).to.have.text('Have This Name')
          })
```

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I would not use `.each()`, only one will pass but any other will fail.

Use `.contains()` if your text is specific enough (not in multiple options)

```js
cy.contains('[id="names"] option', 'Have This Name')  // fails only if 
                                                      // no option has the text
```

If you have to match exactly, filter the options

```js
cy.get('[id="names"] option')
  .filter((idx, el) => el.innerText === 'Have This Name')  // fails if filter 
                                                           // returns 0 items
```

---

If you want `.each()` for another reason, this will do

```js
let found;
cy.get('[id="names"] option')
  .each(($option) => {
    if ($option.text() === 'Have This Name') {
      found = $option
      return false // return now, have found it
    }
  })
  .then(() => {    // after loop exit
    expect(found).to.have.text('Have This Name')
  })
```

Comment: Thank you very much Kegne, you give me other options to do this othen than trying to Select the option.

Comment: By the way, cy.contains('[id="names"] option', 'Have This Name') is not working, but the filter is working fine, and, to do the opposite, success if text is not found, i'm using my each that is working only with "not.have" 

        cy.get('[id="IdCategoria"] option').each(($ele) => {
            expect($ele).to.not.have.text(cpfgerado + ' - DESATIVADO')
          })

I have no idea why this script just get ruined if I remove the "not" 

But, ok, It's working, I guess...

Comment: cy.contains('[id="names"] option', 'Have This Name') is working for me. Thanks

Answer (score -1):

You can handle the scenario like this-

```
 cy.get('[id="names"] option').then(($ele) => 
 {
    if ($ele.text().includes('Have This Name')) 
    {
     // do your statements           
    } 
    else 
    {
      // do your statements      
    }
  })
```